# Android Notification Intent called based on condition

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

My app adds a notification which when clicked, should redirect the user to google play store. The notification is basically to direct user to download an app from google store. But there is a catch; the notification should redirect user only if the app is not installed i.e: when notification is clicked, check if app is installed; if not, take user to Google play store. How do I achieve that?

Should I add a dummy activity to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not specified any activity class in the pending intent specified for your notification add one and in that activity class, check whether the application is installed using the package name specified in your google play store app url,

- if installed keep your activity open if your wish to or finish.
- If not installed finish your activity after opening the url in playstore app.

Another way is to handle this thing is using custom BroadcastReceiver, using [PendingIntent.getBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)). So same as your check implemented in your activity, you can implement it in BroadcastReceiver class and handle the action likewise.

Answer (score 0):

try this once,check with your package name

```
  boolean check_app_install = check_appInstalled("com.Example.package");
                if(check_app_install) {
                    //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
                    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.Example.package");
                    startActivity(LaunchIntent);

                    System.out.println("App is already installed on phone");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("App is not  installed on phone");
                }

    private boolean check_appInstalled(String uri) {
                PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                boolean app_installed;
                try {
                    pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                    app_installed = true;
                }
                catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    app_installed = false;
                }
                return app_installed;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add dummy activity.
In that activity, add this code in `onCreate` to handle app is available in the android phone or not:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String packageName = "INSERT PACKAGE NAME OF APP"; 
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if(launchIntent != null){
   startActivity(launchIntent);
}
 else{
   String googlePlayStoreLink = "INSERT URL OF PLAYSTORE LINK";
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(googlePlayStoreLink)));
}
```

Comment: Won't there be flickering i.e with activity launch and then another activity?